# Are both "**listing** of items" and "**list** of items", grammatical and idiomatic? If yes, when should I use the former?

Tags: meaning

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696131/10449636) says

> It gives you an alphabetical **listing** of valid names (attributes) in the scope (object). This is pretty much the meaning of the word directory in english.

As a non-native english speaker, I would say "It gives you an alphabetical **list** of valid names".

I've no clue whether it is a gerund or a present participle, I don't know if the expression **listing** of valid names is idiomatic either.

Are both "**listing** of items" and "**list** of items",  grammatical and idiomatic? If yes, when should I use the former?

Any help would be appreciated.

I know both [list](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/list) and [listing](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/listing) could be used as an noun, and they are synonyms. I've searched these on Oxford dictionary and didn't get a guide when should I use **listing**.

Comment: Hello, yaojp. ELU is probably different from most sites in that a reasonable amount of (linked and correctly attributed) research is expected to be given with questions. Are there no example sentences in online dictionaries that fit either of these patterns? // That said, the difference between 'listing of articles' and 'list of presents' say is/are subtle, and will doubtless be ... er ... enlisted after you've shown some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, both **list** and **listing** are commonly used as count nouns, and they are synonymous.

But secondly, though their denotations are virtually identical, in some situations, one is easily the preferred choice.

> a shopping list
>
> Consistently ranked in the top four of the Financial Times listings

The [Cambridge Business English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/listing) largely emphasises the synonymity:

> **listing** noun [C]
>
> a list, or one part of a list:
>
> *Here you will find a comprehensive listing of all transportation websites.*
>
> *Do you have a phone listing for A. P. Morrow Inc?*

though the [Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary & Thesaurus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/listing) points out what it sees as an additional requirement for 'listing' (and adds the 'item on a list' sense):

> **listing** noun [C] (RECORD)
>
> a list of information that is published regularly, or an item on this list:
>
> *I'll check the TV listings to see what's on tonight.*
>
> *The site maintains a listing of free events for children in the area.*

Both 'list of NP' and 'listing of NP' are regularly found.

I'd say that the difference is essentially one of register (as in the first examples): mundane / naive vs 'advanced' / sophisticated / official (wannabe?) / technical.  'TV listings' is doubtless an appeal for respectability.

The choice of the ing-form variant where both it and an associated 'normal' noun are available often stresses the action rather than the article / deed ... (eg 'walking [is good for you]' / 'a walk'), but here I believe that nuance is eclipsed by the formal / informal flavour.

Comment: Thank you so much. What does "NP" stands for?

Comment: Any (suitable, here) noun phrase. A list of local newsagents / a listing of next week's programmes.